# Choosing MAX value by id in a view?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by, min

I have created a simple view based on a few columns in our database

```
ALTER VIEW [BI].[v_RCVLI_Test] AS
Select distinct
    Borger.CPRnrKort as CPR,
    (...)
    IndsatsDetaljer.VisitationId as VisitationsId,
    Indsats.KatalogNavn as IndsatsNavn,
    (case
        when 
        (   
            Indsats.Model = 'SMDB2 Tilbudsmodel' or
            Indsats.Model = 'SMDB2 Samtalemodel' or
            Indsats.Model = 'Tilbudsmodel' or
            Indsats.Model = 'NAB Tilbudsmodel'
        )
        then IndsatsDetaljer.ServicePeriodeStart
        else IndsatsDetaljer.Ikrafttraedelsesdato
        end
    ) as StartDato,
    (case
        when 
        (   
            Indsats.Model = 'SMDB2 Tilbudsmodel' or
            Indsats.Model = 'SMDB2 Samtalemodel' or
            Indsats.Model = 'Tilbudsmodel'
        )
        then (case when IndsatsDetaljer.VisitationSlut = '9999-12-31' then convert(varchar(10), getdate(), 23) else IndsatsDetaljer.VisitationSlut end)
        when
        Indsats.Model = 'NAB Tilbudsmodel'
        then (case when IndsatsDetaljer.NABehandlingSlutDato = '9999-12-31' then convert(varchar(10), getdate(), 23) else IndsatsDetaljer.NABehandlingSlutDato end)
        else (case when IndsatsDetaljer.VisitationSlut = '9999-12-31' then convert(varchar(10), getdate(), 23) else IndsatsDetaljer.VisitationSlut end)
        end
    ) as StopDato,
    Refusion.Handlekommune as Handlekommune,
    replace(Refusion.Betalingskommune, 'Ukendt', 'Kendt') Betalingskommune

from nexus2.Fact_VisiteretTid as Fact

join nexus2.Dim_Paragraf Paragraf
on Fact.DW_SK_Paragraf = Paragraf.DW_SK_Paragraf
join nexus2.Dim_Indsats Indsats
on Fact.DW_SK_Indsats = Indsats.DW_SK_Indsats (...)
```

The cases for StartDato and StopDato are there because those dates come from different columns. I've converted the date '9999-12-31' to the the current date because we'll be doing some time calculations later on, and it's just more convenient.

CPR is the id of a person, VisitationsId is the id for the service the person received.
In theory, There should only be one StartDato and one StopDato per VisitationsId, but because of a glitch in the documentation system, we sometimes get TWO StopDato: one is the correct, and one is '9999-12-31' (now converted to current date).

So I need to group by VisitationsId and then just take the MIN value of StopDato, but I'm kind of unsure how to go about doing that?

| CPR | VisitationsId | StartDato | StopDato | Something Else |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 56 | 2019-01-01 | 2019-12-12 | Something |
| 123 | 56 | 2019-01-01 | 9999-12-31 | Something |
| 123 | 58 | 2019-01-01 | 2019-12-14 | Something |
| 345 | 59 | 2018-11-01 | 9999-12-31 | Something |
| 345 | 55 | 2017-01-02 | 2017-11-12 | Something |
| 345 | 55 | 2017-01-02 | 9999-12-31 | Something |

In the above table I need to remove lines 2 and 6, because the VisitationsId is identical to the previous row, but they diverge on StopDato.

Using a group by anywhere in the query gives me an error on another (seemingly random) column telling me that the column is:

> invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Any suggestions on how I can go about doing this?

Comment: Please create a [mre] with some sample data to illustrate what you are saying. Just filter out all rows with a date of `'9999-12-31'`?

Comment: @DaleK No, '9999-12-31' is only invalid if it's on a row where VisitationsId is not unique. I shouldn't have any duplicate VisitationsId at all, and it's the extra StopDato that's giving the problem.
Other than that, I've done my best afa a minimal reproducible example - with all the joins it's going to be pretty impossible to show sample data...

Comment: @DaleK added a simple table to illustrate better - hope it makes sense!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a filter which tests for this condition?

```
with cte (
    {your current query}
)
select *
from cte T
where not (
    StopDato = '9999-12-31'
    and exists (
       select 1
       from cte T1
       where T1.VisitationsId = T.VisitationsId
       and StopDato != '9999-12-31'
    )
);
```

And you look like you are converting `StopDato` to a varchar which is bad - you should treat dates as dates until you need to display them.

Comment: Feels like the right direction, but because StopDato is a custom column made from several I get "Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure v_RCVLI_Test, Line 73 [Batch Start Line 0]
Invalid column name 'StopDato'." 

Something with my syntax?   not ( StopDato = '9999-12-31' and exists ( select 1 from nexus2.Fact_VisiteretTid where VisitationId = VisitationId ) )

Comment: Try using a CTE as I have updated my question with.

Comment: "And you look like you are converting StopDato to a varchar which is bad - you should treat dates as dates until you need to display them." - Like I said new-ish here. Is there a better way to convert 9999-12-31 to current date?

Comment: Well `convert(varchar(10), getdate(), 23)` should just be `getdate()` and `'9999-12-31'` can be `convert(date, '9999-12-31')`.

Comment: I'm going to accept this as the answer because it works - I just had a brain fart though in my example - remember that in my select I've converted 9999-12-31 to current date... so it's StopDato != 'Current date' that I need... sorry!!

Comment: Alternatively don't convert it until after you have compared it? I'd be worried that you might have legitimate records with the current date.

Comment: I've validated the data and doing it like above doesn't interfere with valid records with the current date

Comment: "convert(varchar(10), getdate(), 23) should just be getdate() and '9999-12-31' can be convert(date, '9999-12-31')" returns DateTime and not date...?

Comment: `convert(date, getdate())` then :) I'm sure you can work that stuff out :)